# Passing variables in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013. I have two variables that have two different cell references. I need to use this in a range in another part of my code.

```
Public i As Integer
Public a, b As Ranges

' i is a public integer that comes from another code - last row number
' in a column, its value for now is 432

a = "Q12" 
b = "Q" & j

Sheets("O&O GS&B Expense Flip").range("**Q12:Q432**").cells  
'.....rest of code
```

instead of Q432 I want **b** to be in the range which would make it dynamic.

Comment: Range(a & ":" & b).Select